# Interaction with linux console in python

Tags: python, linux, console

How I can interaction with linux console in python. Open (or not) window with console, and do any command or just typing something and press enter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use both subprocess and os.
These python modules dont necessarily 'open a console and run a command' rather they interface with your shell.

```
import os
import subprocess
```

eg

```
fileCount = int(subprocess.check_output('ls dir/ | wc -l', shell=True).decode().strip())
```

or

```
pathToOldest = './someDir/' + oldestFileInDir
os.remove(pathToOldest)
```

If youre looking to do run a particular command I would go to a search engine and type 'python run shell commmands' or 'run {enter shell command} in pythonX}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
import os
os.system('ls')
```